# How to get other user's data in cognito in android

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS mobile hub to develop an app. The app is to make users upload data daily. Now I would like to develop another app to see the data they uploaded. How can I get their usernames and get their data in DynamoDB? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the permission model in the all user info viewing app? Is it used by a user role like admin?

Comment: All users can see the data but cannot modify them. And yes, it is used by the admin, any advice? I have found the Listusers in cognito, but I don't know if it can meet my requirement and I don't know how to use it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow, but definitely you can use one of the [Cognito Lambda Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) to customize your flow. By inside the lambda function you can push the users' data to DynamoDB. The username comes as an input in all of the Cognito Lambda triggers.